# How to dynamicly create fields in form?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this simple form

```
<form action="" method="post" class="smart-green">
    <h1>Contract Form 
        <span>Please fill all the texts in the fields.</span>
    </h1>
    <label>
        <span>Client:</span>
        <input type="text" name="client" placeholder="Your Client Name" />
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Your Name (Salesman):</span>
        <input type="text" name="salesman" placeholder="Name" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>Construction Name:</span>
        <input type="text" name="construction" placeholder="Construction Name" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>City:</span>
        <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" />
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Items:</span>
        <input type="text" name="id_item" placeholder="Item" />
    </label>    

     <label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span> 
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Send" /> 
    </label>    
</form>
```

It is a form for orders. I need to be able to enter a value of items I am going to enter (5 for example) and then I need the "Items" input to appear 5 times. I also need to be able to remove it, so user can correct himself. I don't know how to code in Javascript, so is this even possible? How? I need to access it later as an array in my controller. Thats why I have the name of the field as an array. Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT: I have just found something similiar to what I need here: http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery
I just dont want it to be a button, but a field with a input for a number and for it to not have a limit. I wish I knew Javascript :<

EDIT2: Maybe I wrote it unclear, but I CAN use Javascript, I just dont know how to properly programm in it, so if anyone knows how to achieve that in Javascript, I would be glad.

Comment: You should be able to just save the form values to a session array.

Comment: I have no problem processing the data from the form, but I need to build the form first. Like I said, I want to input 5 in a field and 5 more fields should appear with an option to delete them.

Comment: Yeah have a button that basically saves a value to a session that tracks how many dynamic fields are available and if they have values assigned, those are also saved in session array.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to ask the user how many items to order, then when the user submits the page to you, save the form data into an array using [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php). The next page that is shown would provide the item text elements for the user to complete.

You'll basically want to:

- Start session
- If `$_POST['id_item']` is set

  - Save all variables into `$_SESSION`
  - Generate item inputs based on `id_item` using a `for` loop
- If items are provided

  - Retrieve previous form data from `$_SESSION`, marry with new item information
- Otherwise

  - Display initial form

(Personal note: Javascript would make this much nicer and easier)

Comment: Well I could always just ask him for the info with the number of items he wants to enter, submit the form and load the next page with new form only for the items and use a for cycle with the value entered on the page before, but it would be nicer if he could do all of that on one page. But I'll keep that in mind if there will be no other answer, ty :)

Answer (score 0):

Without a scripting language, I don't believe this is possible. I suppose you could use simpler 'inline' scripts to do display subsequent elements, like:

```
<div id="item1div">
Item 1:<input name="item1" value="" onFocus="getElementById('item2div').style.display='block';">
</div>
<div id="item2div" style="display:none;">
Item 2:<input name="item2" value="" onFocus="getElementById('item3div').style.display='block';">
</div>
...
<div id="item10div" style="display:none;">
Item 10: <input name="item10" value="">
</div>
```

This would display each item as the previous item was selected.  It comes with its own problems, and it's a real simplification of what you're asking, but it would accomplish your basic goal without having to write a function in JS.

Comment: I can use a Javascript. It is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I was referring to when I said use sessions + PHP. You can do this all in PHP, though javascript would be optimal. I have not included a way to remove the session inputs, however using other form elements will suffice. Also, I have not done any echoing values on reload. This is only an option if you really do not want to use javascript:

```
<?php
    // Put at top of page
    session_start();
    // Also somewhere at top of page
    // Check post empty and assign post to a session for continual use
    if(!empty($_POST)) {
            $_SESSION['form']   =   $_POST;
        } ?>

<form action="" method="post" class="smart-green">
    <h1>Contract Form 
        <span>Please fill all the texts in the fields.</span>
    </h1>
    <label>
        <span>Client:</span>
        <input type="text" name="client" placeholder="Your Client Name" />
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Your Name (Salesman):</span>
        <input type="text" name="salesman" placeholder="Name" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>Construction Name:</span>
        <input type="text" name="construction" placeholder="Construction Name" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>City:</span>
        <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" />
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Items:</span>
        <input type="text" name="id_item" placeholder="Item" />
    </label>    
    <label for="new">Add Fields</label>
    <select name="new" id="new">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">Add 1</option>
        <option value="2">Add 2</option>
        <option value="3">Add 3</option>
        <option value="4">Add 4</option>
    </select>
    <?php
        // This checks if new has been posted
        if(isset($_POST['new']) && $_POST['new'] >= 1) {
        // Check if there are inputs in the queue
        $count  =   (isset($_SESSION['form']['new_input']) && !empty($_SESSION['form']['new_input']))? count($_SESSION['form']['new_input']):1;
        // Loop
        for($i = $count; $i <= $_POST['new']+$count; $i++) { ?>
    <input type="text" name="new_input[<?php echo $i; ?>]" id="new-<?php echo $i; ?>" />
    <?php }
    }

    // Loop through sessioned inputs
    if(isset($_SESSION['form']['new_input'])) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach($_SESSION['form']['new_input'] as $key => $value) { ?>
    <input type="text" name="new_input[<?php echo $key; ?>]" id="new-<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo strip_tags($value); ?>" />
    <?php }
    } ?>
    <button name="add_new" value="new">Add New</button>

    <label>

        <span>&nbsp;</span> 
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Send" /> 
    </label> 
</form>
```

Comment: Not sure why the down-vote, thanks for the your informative rebuttal whomever you are silent voter. Cheers.

Comment: I understand, this is nice, but I need to input the value of the field myself in a number field. One time I need form with 20 items, one time I need it with 3 and clicking this selected option until I have what I need is not practical. Also I need it to be removable again. Do you know how to do that in Javascript?

Comment: My example just demonstrates the logic behind creating dynamic inputs with just php. What you are trying to do can be done all in php, however it's very clumsy in comparison to JavaScript. Search for "dynamic input jquery" and that will should bring up what you need.